# Calling Obj-C Methods

Tags: objective-c, methods

I want to call a method B using a different method A. The problem is that the aksed parameters of method B is not present in Method A. 
 
here's what I've tried ..

```
-(void) methodA {

     // some code

    CGSize *size = [CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    [self methodB:size];
}

-(void) methodB:(CGSize) size {

    //some code
}
```

There is certainly a better way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your code will be compiled.

CGSize is not an object. 
Refactor to:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
[self methodB:size];
```

Comment: okay .. this works so far, but (method b positions some sprites) the sprites were positioned at 0, 0 and not at the chosen place. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: You should share some more code, or ask another question about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should only wrap `[]` around methods. `CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)` is a function, not a method, so get rid of the square braces. You can tell it's a function because functions look like `functionName(argument1, argument2, ...)` whereas methods look like `[object methodName:argument1 methondNameContinued:argument2]`.

Further, `CGSizeMake` returns a `CGSize` structure, not a pointer to a `CGSize` structure, so ditch the `*` in `*size`.

Then you'll be left with this:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
[self methodB:size];
```

Which is correct.